# Not able to read API

Tags: spring, react-native, api

I am able to read this url in the browser but not with javascript

https://www.planete-sorties.net/api/api/ressources/types

This service is generated like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = URL_RESOURCES_TYPES, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> getTypes() {
    String serviceResult = paramService.getTypes().toString();
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(serviceResult);
    
}
```

Actually I am building a react native app and the error is

**[TypeError: Network request failed]**

I also tried to read the url here https://reqbin.com/ and there is an error.

I can read it this way in Java

```
UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = 
UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(appendHost(URL_RESOURCES_TYPES));
HttpEntity<Map<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(null, getHeaders());
RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateConfig.restTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> serviceResultRE = restTemplate.exchange(uriBuilder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
public ResponseEntity<String> getTypes() {
```

Use

```
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getTypes() {
   return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new JSONObject(string).toMap());
}
```